# align multiple div with 100% width in a line

Tags: html, css

I have 4 div and need to align them in a row, each div contains an image and a span tag, but I am unable to align them in a row as the width of each div is 100%.
is it possible to align them? if not are there any alternatives?

```css
body
{
  box-sizing:boder-box;
  margin:0;
}
.container
{
  width:20%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
}
.item
{
  width:100%;
  height:20%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.img
{
  height:20%;
  width:100%;;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="item">
  <img src="1.jpg" class="img"/>
  <span>some text</span>
 </div>
 <div class="item" >
  <img src="1.jpg" class="img"/>
  <span>some text</span>
 </div>
  <div class="item">
  <img src="1.jpg" class="img"/>
  <span>some text</span>
 </div>
  <div class="item">
  <img src="1.jpg" class="img"/>
  <span>some text</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: display:inline-block is not working.
EDIT: I am trying to create carousal with 100% width using div.

Comment: you are missing .(dot) at line number 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your requirement you can use `white-space:nowrap` and `overflow:hidden` combination. It will align all the items in a row..

And then you can use transform to make slide them.

*<sup>**Note:** I have used `transform:translateX(-30px)` in items to show you a visual..</sup>*

***Stack Snippet***

```css
body {
  box-sizing: boder-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  transform:translateX(-30px);
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.item span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img" />
    <span>some text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img" />
    <span>some text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img" />
    <span>some text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img" />
    <span>some text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the reason i am trying to get them in line is i am trying to create a carousal with width 100%.

Comment: @DevendraRawat so you want display one item at a time...right?

Comment: yes,only 1 item at a time but i will move the div using a button click or using animation.

Answer (score 1):

```
      <html>
<head>
    <style>
    .body
    {
        box-sizing:boder-box;
        margin:0;
    }
        .container
        {
            width:20%;
            height:100%;
            position:relative;
        }
        .item
        {
            width:100%;
            height:20%;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        .img
        {
            height:64%;
            width:365px;;
        }           
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div classs="item">
    <img src="1.jpg" class="img"/>
    <span>some text</span>
 </div>
 <div classs="item" >
    <img src="1.jpg" class="img"/>
    <span>some text</span>
 </div>
  <div classs="item">
    <img src="1.jpg" class="img"/>
    <span>some text</span>
 </div>
  <div classs="item">
    <img src="1.jpg" class="img"/>
    <span>some text</span>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this quite easily with flexbox.
First up though, you've got a typo in your first style block: should be `box-sizing: border-box`, not `box-sizing: boder-box`.

To get the four items to occupy 25% of the space, simply set the `display` declaration to `flex` on `.container`

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

Also, assuming you want the images to occupy the full width of their `.item` containers, you'll want to set the `img` width to `100%`

```
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

This is of source assuming that there aren't any other styles affecting these elements (such as a framework).

Answer (score 0):

You also can use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` which will let your elements behave like a table.

If you replace your `.container` to:

```
.container
        {
            width:20%;
            height:100%;
            position:relative;
            display: table;
        }
```

And add the following:

```
.container > div {
              display: table-cell;
            }
```

the child elements inside the `.container` will be aligned and behave like a `td` element.

Answer (score 0):

I have set `container` to `width:100%` and `item` to `width:20%` and `float left;`

spellings for `class` were wrong in child div. I have Corrected it.

Hope this helps:)

```css
body
{
box-sizing:boder-box;
margin:0;
}
.container
{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
}
.item
{
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  height:auto;
  margin:10px;
}
.img
{
  height:20%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="item">
  <img src="1.jpg" class="img"/>
  <span>some text</span>
 </div>
 <div class="item" >
  <img src="1.jpg" class="img"/>
  <span>some text</span>
 </div>
  <div class="item">
  <img src="1.jpg" class="img"/>
  <span>some text</span>
 </div>
  <div class="item">
  <img src="1.jpg" class="img"/>
  <span>some text</span>
 </div>
</div>
```